# C# JSON library to handle values with escape characters such as '

Tags: c#, json

I would like to serialize an object with a JSON escape character. I saw a similar question that handles JSON with escape character by replacing the value itself. What I would to know is if there is an existing library that already does the job.

example:

```
Person guy = new Person()
{
    Name = "John's Smith"
};

string jsonStr = SomeJsonLib.Serialize(guy);
```

notice that the string has '

Comment: `'` is not an escape character in JSON and requires no special treatment.  Characters which require escaping are `"`, `\ `  and control characters.  See [json.org](http://www.json.org/).  Have a look at the [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library to serialize your guy.  It will handle all the necessary escaping for you.

Comment: I'd second json.net aka newtonsoft